# How to get auto suggestion from server

Tags: autosuggest

How to get auto suggestion from server, list of items in textbox which can be selected in Java/J2EE ?

Comment: Is this for a Java Swing app or a web app? ...

Comment: No, it is not java swing. I want the list of items from server using ajax in my text box feild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using jQuery it has a nice [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin. You will need to build a simple webservice to provide the data.

So you will be building the simple Java backend that deals with getting the data out and then using the autocomplete to consume that data on the front end.

Comment: I have no option but call it the best answer .. +1
Pretty nice post .. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to do it.

Try [this](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Java_Ajax_Frameworks).

Comment: Thank you. How to use this ajax?